# Allow normal users writing to intermittent block devices

Tags: permissions, usb, block-device

I currently do a lot of copying disk images to and from hard disks. They are normally connected via USB.

Normally block devices cannot be written to by normal users, so I do everything as root. I am worried that I might one day by mistake write to `/dev/sda` when I really meant `/dev/sds`.

Is there a way I can tell GNU/Linux to "write protect" `/dev/sda`? Or maybe a way to allow all USB-block devices to be written to by users in group `usbwriters`?

I can easily list the block devices I want to write protect. I cannot, however, list the devices I want to write to, because they are often temporarily connected using USB.

Here is the udev output of one of the devices:

```
# /sbin/udevadm info -a -p $(/sbin/udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdn)

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host16/target16:0:0/16:0:0:1/block/sdn':
    KERNEL=="sdn"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{capability}=="d1"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}=="media_change"
    ATTR{events_async}==""
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{hidden}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{removable}=="1"
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="13563904"
    ATTR{stat}=="      77        0     4168      224        0        0        0        0        0      140      224"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host16/target16:0:0/16:0:0:1':
    KERNELS=="16:0:0:1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{blacklist}=="FORCELUN"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{inquiry}==""
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x81"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x1"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x81"
    ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
    ATTRS{model}=="USB Flash Disk  "
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{rev}=="1100"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="5"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="General "

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host16/target16:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target16:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/host16':
    KERNELS=="host16"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="300mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="1100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="29"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="090c"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="General"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB Flash Disk"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="FBK1611110100145"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="981"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0415"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.15.0-96-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="918"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="24"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x04"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0686"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1025"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Depending on your usage, you might be able to assign a common LABEL to devices and refer to them by label in /etc/fstab for mounting, or in your shell scripts lookup the label and convert it to a device (`findfs LABEL=...`). Similarly UUID, PARTLABEL.

Comment: `LABEL` will not make sense in my case: I am overwriting the full disk with image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add this line to "/etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules":

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

The changes from @StephenKitt's answer are:

- the removal of `ATTR{removable}=="1"`. If `ATTR{removable}=="1"` was included partitions (`/dev/sdn1`) would not be affected.
- putting it it 99-local... instead of 01-local... because otherwise group would be overwritten in 50-...

(`udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdn)` was absolutely crucial in solving this. Thanks to @StephenKitt for that).

Comment: Ah, right, your question mentioned disks, not partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to protect devices from root, I would make sure that removable USB device nodes are writeable by `usbwriters` group, using a `udev` rule such as

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", ATTR{removable}=="1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="660", GROUP="usbwriters"
```

Add this somewhere in `/etc/udev/rules.d` (I have a `01-local.rules` file for local rules), and add yourself to the group you used.

Comment: That sound like a reasonable solution. But I cannot make it work: I have added /etc/udev/rules.d/01-local.rules with the one line you suggest, run `/etc/init.d/udev restart`, but when I plug in a new device `ls -l /dev/sd` says it is group writable by `disk` not `plugdev`. Is there another step that I am missing?

Comment: I don’t think so, I added the rule and it worked immediately for me (without even restarting `udev`). I’m not in front of my computer now, but `/sbin/udevadm info -a -p $(/sbin/udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)` should show you the attributes for `sdb` (replace as appropriate) — could you check they match the rule?

Comment: Looking at the output it looks as if the rule would match. Does `udev` spit out some debugging somewhere?

Comment: You can monitor `udev` events with `sudo udevadm monitor -p`, and perhaps more usefully, test the rules which would be applied to a path with `udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdn)` — the latter will show you exactly what would be done to the new node.

Comment: Hmm... On my system `test` does the wrong thing, it changes the group back to `disks` (probably because one of the attributes we test against isn’t set in `test` mode).

Comment: I think I found it: It first changes the group correctly, but later it is hit by the default rule. I will test if renaming 01... to 99... will fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107767/discussion-between-ole-tange-and-stephen-kitt).